# Why is EVENT_END_TIMEZONE not used?

Tags: android, timezone, android-calendar

When changing the timezone of an event with both [`EVENT_TIMEZONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#EVENT_TIMEZONE) and [`EVENT_END_TIMEZONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#EVENT_END_TIMEZONE) set, for all calendar apps I tried (*[aCalendar 0.99.8](http://www.tapirapps.de/de/home.htm), Google's default calendar 4.4.2*), [`EVENT_END_TIMEZONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#EVENT_END_TIMEZONE) is not updated to the new timezone, although the end time is displayed according to the new timezone.

**Why isn't the end timezone set to the same value as the start/regular timezone?** Am I missing some other timezone-related fields that have to be set in order for [`EVENT_END_TIMEZONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#EVENT_END_TIMEZONE) to be used / updated?

---

As I was asked to provide some code, here is one possible way to define an event showing the described behavior (note that, depending on the context of your code, you may need to use a different URI and/or add additional fields):

```
final ContentResolver cr = /* ... */;
final long calendarId = /* ... */;

final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Test");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, 1428307200000L);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Berlin");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, 1428314400000L);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE,"Europe/Berlin");
final Uri result = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Once the event is changed to another timezone using any of the two apps listed above, its `EVENT_END_TIMEZONE` is preserved (`"Europe/Berlin"`), while the event's end is displayed relative to the new timezone (something different from `"Europe/Berlin"`).

Comment: It would really help if you could give example code, including what you expected vs what happened.

Comment: @JonSkeet The question is about how calendar apps handle timezones relative to the content provider, not directly about writing code. What kind of example code did you have in mind?

Comment: If code isn't involved, then it's not really a suitable question for SO... It's really unclear what you're asking for at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did not say that code is not involved, however this question is not about writing one specific piece of code but about [the contract between the calendar provider and applications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html), which applies to all ways accessing calendar data, independent of the actual code or tools used. More specifically, the question is about why official and unofficial implementations I found do not update one specific field within said contract, while they would need to according to my understanding of the documentation.

Comment: If it applies to all ways of accessing calendar data, then you should be able to demonstrate it *in code* very simply, right? Of course, if you don't want to make your question any clearer or easier for people to help you, that's your call - I'm just telling you that at the moment, it's unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure if we talk at cross purposes. The behaviour I'm asking about is **not** happening in my code, but somewhere in the calendar apps I listed in the question. For what it's worth, I added one possible way to create such an event to the question.

Comment: That's at least better... But this does sound like it's more asking about why particular apps behave in a particular way than being a programming question...

Comment: @JonSkeet if this particular app would not be the official calendar app from Google, I'd agree. But as the official app and at least one other app act that way, my understanding of the contract is likely to be wrong. And the contract, imho, is very much on-topic on this site.

Comment: I suspect it's really a matter of the Google Calendar event model being a bit richer than the mobile app is willing to display... which leads to difficulties in terms of how much you change. (If you create a calendar entry with different start and end time zones in code, are they persisted properly, and do they show correctly on the web app?)

Comment: Looking into android source code,. i don't see EVENT_END_TIMEZONE being updated at all. only EVENT_TIMEZONE has been managed.